# SoftLayer API: retrieve state of a bare metal server

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm trying to get the state of a bare metal server through the API. There is

```
['hardwareStatus']['status']
```

but this is set to 5 both for a server that is running, and for a server that is shut down. Is it possible to retrieve this info through the API?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what kind of status you are looking for, but if you want to know if a server is running or not, you can use these methods:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/getServerPowerState

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/isPingable

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following request:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/[hardware_id]/getServerPowerState
Method: GET
```

**Some references can help you:**

[get Server Power State](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/getServerPowerState)

[PowerOnOffBaremetalInstance](https://github.com/uzresk/softlayer/blob/master/src/main/java/instance/PowerOnOffBaremetalInstance.java)

[Server:state](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/fog-softlayer/0.4.7/Fog/Compute/Softlayer/Server:state)

Regards.